# Regex only finding one match

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
TRANSCRIPT    WS000006.1 (802 nt)
PARENT_CONTIG WS000006
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..802
                     /organism="Winter skate"
     CDS             complement(3..443)
                     /protein_id="WS000006.1_orf1"
                     /orf_type="5prime_partial"
                     /blastp_hit_swissprot="MALD2_HUMAN"
                     /blastp_hit_uniprot="Q8N4S9"
                     /blastp_hit_name="MARVEL domain-containing protein 2"
                     /blastp_hit_identity="61.29%"
                     /blastp_hit_evalue="5e-47"
                     /pfam_hit_accession="PF07303.8"
                     /pfam_hit_id="Occludin_ELL"
                     /pfam_hit_name="Occludin homology domain"
                     /pfam_hit_evalue="7.3e-28"
                     /translation="AKSFPSRCNGAGTLNKSIPAGFIPKPLIVPDYVTKYPKIETAEE
                     RERYKGVFNDQYAEYRELHTEIYVANRKFGELKTLIERLPHYVETSEEHR
                     RIMKILEDYKEKKNDPTFVEKKQRCTYLKNKLSYIKLRIQEYDLDCDSSS
                     SY*"

                     /go_cellular_component="plasma membrane|0005886"
                     /go_cellular_component="tight junction|0005923"
                     /go_biological_process="cell-cell junction organization|0045216"
                     /go_biological_process="sensory perception of sound|0007605"
ORIGIN
        1 CTGCCAAGAG CTTCCCGTCG CGGTGCAACG GTGCGGGCAC GCTCAACAAG TCCATTCCCG 
       61 CAGGATTCAT CCCGAAGCCT CTCATCGTTC CCGATTACGT CACAAAGTAC CCGAAGATTG 
      121 AGACTGCAGA GGAGAGAGAA CGGTACAAGG GTGTGTTCAA TGACCAGTAC GCGGAATATC 
      181 GGGAGCTACA CACTGAGATC TATGTGGCCA ACAGGAAGTT TGGGGAACTG AAGACTCTGA 
      241 TCGAGAGACT GCCCCACTAC GTCGAGACAT CAGAGGAGCA CAGACGTATA ATGAAGATCC 
      301 TCGAAGATTA CAAGGAGAAA AAGAATGACC CAACATTTGT GGAGAAGAAG CAACGATGCA 
      361 CTTACCTGAA GAACAAACTC TCGTACATCA AGCTGCGAAT CCAGGAGTAT GATCTAGACT 
      421 GTGACTCCTC CAGCAGTTAC TGAACAAAAT CTCACATCAT TCATCATTAA TATTTTCATT 
      481 ATTTTTCTTC TAGTGCAGAT AGGATTCATT TGGGCCGTGG AGTGTGTATG TATGTGTGTG 
      541 TGTGTATGTA TGTGTGCGTG TGTACGTATA TGTGTGTGTG TACACCGTGT TGTGTGTACC 
      601 TGTGTGTACG TGTATGTATG TGTGTGTACG TGTGTGTGTG CGCATGATTA TATGTGTGTG 
      661 TGAATATGAG TGCGGGTGTG TGCATATGTG TGTGTGTGAA ATAATATAGT ATTTCGTAGT 
      721 TCAGAGCTTA TTTGTTAAGT TTAATAGCGT GATGGCTGTC AGGAAGAAGC TGTTCCTCAA 
      781 TGTAGATGTT ACAGTTTTCA GT
//
```

And I want to get the lines that begin with /go_

So I constructed the following regex: `\/go_.+?=".+?"`
Which to my mind should get the /go_ bit, then the rest of the line before the = character, and then the final part after the = character which is inside quotation marks.

However on an online regex tester (https://regex101.com/), I'm only getting the first of the /go_ lines as a match. How can I match all the lines?

Thanks.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: At that site, you need to [type `g` to the options field](https://regex101.com/r/oD3aG8/1).

Comment: Actually, in the regex tester you are trying it, you must specify the flag "g" in the input after the regex input. "g" means global search, get all occurrences....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern could be:

```
\s*\/go_.*
```

However, you need to pass the `g` (*global*) to flag to catch all matches:
https://regex101.com/r/lW7mQ5/1 . Depending on your programming language and context you may also want to pass the `m` (*multiline*) option and change the pattern to `^\s*\/go_` (Note the `^` which stands for beginning of the *line* when `m` gets passed)

**Btw, one thing.** Please take care on how to ask a question on SO. You should a) create the shortest possible example instead of just pasting a huge amount of text, b) explain what you are exactly doing, in which programming language and what you've tried so far(!).

Answer (score 0):

In that particular regular expression engine, using the g parameter in the second text entry box (after the /) will cause it to find all occurrences. This is because that engine is not searching your string line by line, but rather as a single unitary blob of text to be searched. Thus, it finds the first match and quits. The g switch tells it to find all matches.

The upshot of this is that you will need to find out how to scan a multi-line string for all matches in the target language you are using. Here's some Ruby that does the job:

```
s=<input string above>
s.scan(/\/go_.+?=".+?"/).each do |match|
    puts match
end
```

And the output is:

```
/go_cellular_component="plasma membrane|0005886"
/go_cellular_component="tight junction|0005923"
/go_biological_process="cell-cell junction organization|0045216"
/go_biological_process="sensory perception of sound|0007605"
```